# get the count of values that both the string/array contains

Tags: arrays, vb.net, count

I originally have strings like these: (which I got using the GROUP_CONCAT() function of MySQL)

```
oldArrStr = "1, 2, 79, 5, 6, 7"
newArrStr = "4, 6, 2, 13, 7, 9"
```

i happen to need to compare newArrStr with oldArrStr and it should return the counts of the matched values. In this case: oldArrStr and newArrStr both have: 2, 6, 7 so it shoud return 3

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim oldArrStr = "1, 2, 79, 5, 6, 7"
Dim newArrStr = "4, 6, 2, 13, 7, 9"

Dim count = _
    oldArrStr.Split(","c).Select(Function (x) x.Trim()) _
        .Intersect(newArrStr.Split(","c).Select(Function (x) x.Trim())) _
        .Count()
```

I get three as per your question.

You can fiddle with it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GBt5D2).